# ActionSheet with SegmentControl Swift 3

Tags: swift

Is it possible implement SegmenControl in ActionSheet (UIAlertController) How can I do this? Thanks.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIc5g.png)

Comment: You can present a `viewController` with the view background color as `clear`. Adding a `tableViewController` in that `viewController` and presenting it.
Add the tableView in a way that it only covers half of the screen and you can achieve the desired functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another way of achieving the required functionality without the  UIActionSheet:-

- In your storyboard make a new `UIViewController`
- Add a `UITableView` in your newly created `UIViewController`
- Set Presentation to Over Current Context in the attributes of your `ViewController`
- Change the Background color of your `View` in your `ViewController` to `Clear`
- Create a `Seague` from the `ViewController` to your newly created View controller and set it to Present Modally.
- Add the constraints to your `UITableView` that it covers half of the screen.

Comment: Thanks man. I used your solution and I used as Present Modaly.